# C++ shared pointers of parent-children classes

Tags: c++, destructor, smart-pointers, ownership-semantics

I have a scenario in which I need to collect all the objects of a type in a collection, but I also need a collection of some of its inherited types. Example:

```
class Particle: public someClass
{
    ...
    public:
        static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Particle>> particleCollection;
}

class ChargedParticle: public Particle
{
    ...
    public:
    static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ChargedParticle>> chargedParticleCollection;
}
```

However when I want to destroy these objects, I actually call the destructor twice for every ChargedPartice:

```
Particle::particleCollection.clear(); // Okay
ChargedParticle::chargedParticleCollection.clear(); // Error: particles are already deleted
```

How can I both have a collection of the child objects stored in its static container and have smart pointers pointing on them by one of their parent classes?

I want to be able to create objects from the parent class too, and have the parent's static smart pointer vector be the owner of these objects.

My idea is that I somehow define a custom deleter for the parent class smart pointers that only calls the destructor, when the object is not an element of the child class' collection. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you use static member to store this particles?

Comment: When using `shared_ptr` properly, double destructor calls should not happen. You should show more code, possibly a mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко Simple use-case: I want to calculate the force on a charged particle, due to electrostatic interactions. For this I need to know all the other charged particle positions.

Comment: Maybe then you should keep particles only in base class? Without creating possible duplicates?

Comment: I'm not creating duplicates, just having two owners of the same object. And I need to have separate collections for both of them, because they are used for diferent kinds of operations, and I don't want to filter a collection and convert it to a collection of different kind of pointers (which is actually quite expensive) every time I call a child operation.

Comment: This is a case where you need to provide an MCVE if anyone is to have a hope of helping you.   Lacking an MCVE, I suggest you need to look closely at the documentation of `shared_ptr`.  A `shared_pointer` can actually manage two distinct pointers - one it owns and one it shares.   If you mess up handling of that sort of thing, consequences can be the sort of problem you're having.

Comment: You are probably creating shared pointers from regular pointers. This defeats the purpose of shared pointers. Remove regular pointers to `Particle` and all its derived classes from your program and replace them with shared pointers. One kind of pointer you cannot remove is `this`. If you have to create a shared pointer from `this`, you must inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @n.m. He wants to create a self-registering class, which can't be done with `std::shared_ptr` and `std::enable_shared_from_this`, see his comment in my answer and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d82244848f9ff1ca)

Comment: From cppreference, _It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17)std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the shared_ptr constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since C++17)._

Comment: @n.m. I only create smart pointers from "this". std..enable_shared_from_this does not seem to help this cause...

Comment: The real problem is you can't manage the non-existence object

Comment: Yes, you cannot generally use `shared_from_this` in a constructor before any other shared ptr takes ownership. If you need this, you can create the very first shared pointer from `this` without using `shared_from_this`, but you need to be careful with it (ie.g. `make_shared()` probably won't work with this scheme). Better write a factory and register from the creation method rather than from a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Every `ChargedParticle` is at the same time is a `Particle` so calling `Particle::particleCollection.clear();` would be enough to remove all allocated objects.

To use shared pointer in your case you need to have base class (either `someClass` or `Particle`) to be inherited from [`std:: enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) thus shared pointer created from it will share the same counter. In your example these are two different instances of shared pointer that know nothing about each other.

And I don't see any reason for virtual destructor to not be enough for your needs.

Comment: The clearing of the particleCollection does not help me with the chargedParticleCollection. After the one-sided clear if I loop on it, it will contain dangling pointers.

I use virtual destructors, but I've never heard of this std::enable_shared_from_this class. I will check it out, thanks :)

Comment: @AdamHunyadi You can consider using `std::weak_ptr`, or removing items from appropriate array in destructor.

Comment: How do I use std::weak_ptr in this case?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi weak pointer has member `expired` which can tell if the object is already deleted. But it all depends on how you want to manage the ownership

Comment: I understand, but how do I put weak pointers of the derived class to a vector? I cannot make them weak ptrs of base class, because I'm using them in a collection of derived objects. I cannot make it a weak ptr of derived either, because then I cannot make it stick to a shared ptr of a base class.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi weak pointers can be converted to shared pointers easily. But I don't know who owns these objects. If owning is shared than use shared pointers everywhere, if lifetime of the object defined in single place than use shared pointer there and weak pointers in all other places.

Comment: He wants to use it from constructor to create self -registering class, then it's impossible because there are no owner at the first place

Comment: @teivaz anyway, it only works if and only if all constructor doesn't throw, which is hard to archive

Answer (score 0):

If you use it properly, there's no problem, class's name is not the same with your class name, but I don't think it matters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
struct Base
{
    Base() { std::cout << "  Base::Base()\n"; }
    // Note: non-virtual destructor is OK here
    ~Base() { std::cout << "  Base::~Base()\n"; }
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    Derived() { std::cout << "  Derived::Derived()\n"; }
    ~Derived() { std::cout << "  Derived::~Derived()\n"; }
};

int main() {  
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> base_vector;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> derived_vector;
    auto d = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    derived_vector.push_back(d);
    base_vector.push_back(d);
    // 2 function call below does not matter
    base_vector.clear();
    derived_vector.clear();

}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d298b666ad2c3417) is expanded from example in [Cpp Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

You can't create a self-registering class with `std::shared_ptr` because you need to inherit from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), but you can't call `shared_from_this()` in the constructor because:

> It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17)std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the shared_ptr constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since C++17).

Comment: This is no good, since in my Base class constructor call, I cannot have a pointer to a derived class.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi that means you want to self-register your class to that list?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi And the problem is, when the constructor hadn't finished, the object haven't existed, if the constructor throws, the object isn't existed, that says your vector have a non-exist object

Comment: Hence, consider using Factory design pattern instead

Comment: Yes, self registering as in giving ownership to these containers during construction.

Comment: Then, what happens if the construction fail after registration, let's say it's success in base classs and fail in derived class

Comment: @AdamHunyadi To be more clear, `std::enable_shared_from_this` complains about `bad weak_ptr` as you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f609864c32abd83) and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d82244848f9ff1ca)